# can i write an Autosave plugin for microsoft windows notepad?

Tags: c#, .net

I use notepad for writing daily notes.some times when system gets restarted by accidentally, I loose my content.

So my question is"can I write an auto-save plugin for notepad" ?
Please let me know if I can write an auto-save plugin for Notepad using C#.NET.
I know about Notepad++ but I want to use notepad only.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Could we know why you don't want to use notepad++ ?

Comment: i would like to use notepad as it is simple application and got an idea that why can't we write plugin for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way of doing this because NotePad is a separate application and you don't have its code. Even if you did have the code, I'm highly sure it wouldn't be in a .NET-based language.

There is an alternate though. You could recreate entire NotePad from scratch in .NET. Believe me it won't take more than a couple hours for a guy who knows his tools (someone out there might already have done that). Then you can add any new features at your choice.

Yet another way would be hooking into NotePad's low-level messages through Platform calls and trying to somehow inject your features into it, but that's something I'm not an expert at and that would probably take more effort/expertise than writing your own NotePad from scratch.